# HostBinding to value works only the first time

Tags: angular, angular2-hostbinding

I have a ControlValueAccessor directive that performs value formatting but its `@HostBinding('value')` works only the first time.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  Value: {{value}}<br/>
  <input type="text" uppercase [(ngModel)]="value">
  <button type="button" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  reset() {
    this.value = 'Reset';
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[uppercase]',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => UpperCaseInputDirective), multi: true }],
})
export class UpperCaseInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @HostBinding('value') lowerValue = '';

  ...
}
```

Please see full example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vfahu3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

1. When I click Reset button for the first time, is sets ngModel to "Reset" and text of `<input>` to "reset" as expected.
2. Then I edit the input value to "Test" and value is propagated back to model as "TEST" as expected.
3. When I click Reset button for the second time, ngModel is set to "Reset" as expected but text of `<input>` stays with "Test". I would expect it to change to "reset" as it did in point 1.

Can you explain me this behavior? Any clues?

*Side note:* I know the example above could be implemented by other means, but it just a simplification of case where I am using `<input type="datetime-local>` and the directive translates input value to ISO format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the value was not updated due to Angular optimization - it does not propagate value to DOM if it thinks that value did not change. In point 1 it changes bound variable to value "Reset" and in point 3 it "thinks" the value is still "Reset" and therefore it does not update DOM.

When I update bound variable `this.lowerValue` in `onChange` listener (point 2) then Reset button works event in point 3:

```
  @HostListener('change', ['$event']) onChange(event: Event) {
    if (event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      this.lowerValue = event.target.value?.toLocaleUpperCase();
    }
    this._onChangeCallback(this.lowerValue);
  }
```